# Need to sum a column if 2 or 3 columns contain a specific text with a criteria

Tags: excel, find, concatenation, sumifs

```
 Column1      Column 2      Column 3     Column 4   Column 5   Column 6
  ABC is good    CNN           $150         ABC       NBA     R1
  Better life    N-H           $40          LIT       MNM     R2
  Nice Job       ABC is good   $35          MN        ABC     R1
  Poor           H-I           $200         ITL       ABC     R4
  Best           TI            $120         SQL       ABC     R3
  Poor life      N-T           $40          LT        NM      R2
  Great          BE            $800         ABC       BEF     R3
```

I am currently using the array formula below to give me the total..

```
  = SUM(IF(ISERR(FIND("ABC",CONCATENATE(A1:A7,B1:B7,D1:D7,E1:E7))), 0, C1:C7))
```

I need to add criteria in the formula.. to sum how many ABCs for R1 ? Similarly for R2 and R3 - 3 formulae

Comment: Whenever your sample data has *abc* in columns A or B, it also has *abc* in either column D or E. Is this standard behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I flipped the logic of your original so you only had to provide the values in column C, not zeroes for non-matches and added a nested IF statement to your array formula.

```
=SUM(IF(F1:F7=F1, IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("ABC",CONCATENATE(A1:A7,B1:B7,D1:D7,E1:E7))), C1:C7)))
```

I've simply referenced F1 for the *R1* value but you can hard-code the text in or reference any cell containing *R1*. You will also want to make some of those cell range references absolute so you can fill down. Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd> (but you knew that already!).